# How to reference something in the anonymous namespace of a NuGet package?

Tags: c#, nuget

I have to use the NuGet package of someone in my team. The problem is that he has not put the functions I need to use in a namespace that I can reference in my own project, but he left them under an anonymous namespace. The source code of the NuGet looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using TaskScheduler;
/* ... other imports ... */

class Program
{
    public static List<IRegisteredTask> GetTasksList(string taskFolder)
    {
        List<IRegisteredTask>? listTasks = new List<IRegisteredTask>();
        ITaskService taskService = new TaskScheduler.TaskScheduler();
        taskService.Connect();

        listTasks = ProcessTaskFoler(taskService.GetFolder(taskFolder), listTasks);

        return listTasks;
    }

    /* ... and other functions */
}
```

The NuGet consists of several classes as well as a bunch of static methods in a static class called 'Program'. The problem is that in my own project I also have an implicit Program class (I can't rename it I guess, it's the Program.cs of a ASP.NET Core MVC app) inside an anonymous namespace. I have to use the 'GetTasksList' method of the NuGet here, but I can't reference it.

Typing 'Program' seem to reference the current class and not the one of the NuGet. Also typing global::Program does not work. Is there a solution to reference the specific class inside an anonymous namespace of a NuGet ?

I am aware that this is a bad architecture for a NuGet libray, but that's how it is at this time. I would like to know if it's still possible to reference things inside an anonymous namespace of a NuGet package, notably when the name of said things (class Program) conflicts with something inside my project.

Thanks for your help

Comment: *"I can't rename it I guess"* - You can, and if it's where `Main` is, you can select the entrypoint in the project properties once you've renamed the class. It's unfortunate that this other developer and the NuGet package they created (and you must now use) will force you to go this route, but it's a valid workaround.

Comment: And it's the ***"global namespace"***, not "anonymous namespace".

Comment: There's nothing special about `Program` - you can rename your local one, or put it in a namespace, and perhaps use explicit `global::My.Namespace.Program` to refer to it?

Comment: @MarcGravell code shown makes "Program" from NuGet `internal` - so no amount of code changes in the calling code will allow to use that class... OP needs reflection (or fixing code sample in the post to reflect reality).

Answer (score 2):

You could use aliases, they are designed to work around conflicting names.
In `.csproj` (required NuGet 5.7+):

```xml
<PackageReference Include="YourNuGetPackageId" Version="1.0.0" Aliases="NuGetAlias" />
```

When you need to call something:

```cs
extern alias NuGetAlias;

class Consumer
{
    public void Consume()
    {
        var data = NuGetAlias::Program.GetTasksList("...");
    }
}
```

Note that `Program` class looks `internal`, so calling it directly might still be an issue (reflection or `UnsafeAccessorAttribute` from future `.net8` will help here).

Reflection way (does not need aliases, will break through `internal`/`private` classes/methods):

```cs
static class ProgramWrapper
{
    // out argument is used to infer T automatically
    private static void LoadMethod<T>(out T loadedMethod, Type type, string name,
        BindingFlags flags) where T : Delegate
    {
        var method = type.GetMethod(name, flags)
            ?? throw new ArgumentException("Method not found.", nameof(name));
        // use expressions to create a delegate instead of dealing with MethodInfo
        var parameters = Array.ConvertAll(
            method.GetParameters(),
            static p => Expression.Parameter(p.ParameterType));
        loadedMethod = Expression
            .Lambda<T>(Expression.Call(null, method, parameters), parameters)
            .Compile();
    }

    public static readonly Func<string, List<IRegisteredTask>> GetTasksList;

    static ProgramWrapper()
    {
        // first we need to get assembly reference
        // option 1 - find type exported by the assembly and do typeof()
        var assembly = typeof(AnyTypeExportedByNugetAssembly).Assembly;
        // option 2 - by name
        // var assembly = Assembly.Load("AssemblyName");

        // find type
        var type = assembly.GetType("Program", throwOnError: true);

        // repeat for each required method
        LoadMethod(out GetTasksList, type, "GetTasksList",
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
    }
}

class Consumer
{
    public void Consume()
    {
        var data = ProgramWrapper.GetTasksList("...");
    }
}
```